# DotNetNuke instance won't start

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

I installed the Vanila DNN availible on Azure. App Service with SQL Database. I was able to to this last week without issues. I started the set up and used the wizard to configure it. Now the site won't start up. Getting a 500 error right away

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   DotNetNuke.HttpModules.OutputCaching.OutputCacheModule.OnResolveRequestCache(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +600
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +141    System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.b__0() +26    System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +101
>   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0() +22
>   Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase
>   context, Action step) +64
>   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.b__0(Action
>   nextStepAction) +54    System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action
>   executionStep) +85
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
>   +9980113    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +7S

How do I debug this? I can't seem to find any logs that are useful. In Application insights. it states the same error message

UPDATE Here is the EventLog:
GENERAL_EXCEPTION

```
<LogProperties>
  <LogProperty>
    <PropertyName>AbsoluteURL</PropertyName>
    <PropertyValue>/default.aspx</PropertyValue>
  </LogProperty>
  <LogProperty>
    <PropertyName>DefaultDataProvider</PropertyName>
    <PropertyValue>DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke</PropertyValue>
  </LogProperty>
  <LogProperty>
    <PropertyName>ExceptionGUID</PropertyName>
    <PropertyValue>b038f0be-9ad9-4687-8820-efc9e45b0b22</PropertyValue>
  </LogProperty>
</LogProperties>
```

Comment: Have you checked in EventLog table from DNN database?

Comment: YES its basic GENERAL_EXCEPTION: